# How to set the DNS server on Nexus One?

Tags: settings, networking, nexus-one, dns

The ISP I use on my N1 doesn't allow me to open facebook. Using a PC, I can use Google DNS server (8.8.8.8) to by-pass them but on N1, I can't find where to put the stufff.

Please help if you know how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you're on Wifi, have a look in Wi-Fi settings > menu|Advanced.

It looks like it's easier when you're on Wifi than when you're on a celular signal (3 or 2.5g).I've found a [blog post here](http://www.carson.alittlekitchen.com/changing-android-mobile-data-dns-server-settings/) that seems to do what your asking, but you may need to have rooted the phone, or at least be comfotable with editing a few system bits and bobs.

Answer (score 1):

The following was added as an edit to the question. It seems like it should be an answer.

1. Go to `Setting - Wireless & Network - Wifi settings`
2. Press `Menu` button, and select `Advance`
3. Check `Use Static IP`
4. Enter `IP adress`, `Gateway`, `Netmask` and `DNS Server 1&2` of associated with your LAN networks.

Eg., for me, I use

- ip=`192.168.1.100`
- gateway=`192.168.1.1`
- DNS1=`8.8.8.8`
- DNS2=`8.8.4.4`