# Chrome browser will not connect to intranet web addresses

Tags: chrome-for-android, dns, url

I can access a internal address using `http://companyweb` which redirects to `http://companyweb/default.aspx` from my windows desktop fine. I can also access `http://companyweb` on my iphone.  However, when I type `"http://companyweb"` on my android device it searches the internet. If I type `http://companyweb.domain.local`, the default IIS7 (internet information service - windows web server) homepage is displayed. They are all connected to the same wireless network.  How can i get android to connect to this site?

Thanks

Comment: See also [How to reach local computer via machine name instead of IP?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52140/) / [How use call a local server by name rather than IP?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48770/) / [How to set up tablet to use a local DNS server thru VPN rather than Google's DNS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21513/) / [How to set the DNS server on Nexus One?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/)

Comment: I think i realized the problem now.  Apple and my windows desktop both use DNS suffix's and android doesn't. How do i enter suffixes in android?

Comment: The problem is slightly different: Android *always* uses Google's name servers for name-to-IP conversion, even when an DHCP server suggests differently. Google's name servers cannot resolve your intranet-only names. So to make this work, you will need to change the corresponding configuration. See the first question linked by GAThrawn for details.

Comment: Confirmed my doubt: `getprop | grep -i` shows my local dns as primary and google's as secondary. I bet this issue has to do with Chrome's omnibar (the combined search and uri input box) that detects it erronously as a search instead of an URI.

Comment: @Izzy: not true, on my localnet `http://server` doesn't work while `http://server.lan:8080` does. And by the way, this would break all intranet related networking that depends on DNS. Isnt AOSP itself pretty much Google agnostic whithout the gapps package. Has one tried Firefox?

Comment: Firefox mobile doesn't do this' i suppose it's Chrome's combined search/URI input box (omnibox).

Comment: I've checked my settings (not with `getprop`, but in the WiFi settings, long press the AP, advanced). Before I manually put in my local DNS here, it hat `4.4.4.4` as primary, and `8.8.8.8` as secondary. But that was a while ago: checking right now on one of my newer devices (Android 4.1.1), it correctly uses my DNS as primary, and `4.4.4.4` as secondary. A second device (same manufacturer) shows the same. So I have to take that back at least partially, as described "misbehavior" might be device or version specific.

Comment: I've found a solution.  Not sure how i answer my own question on here.  I've round the full URL I can use internally or externally for SharePoint.  Its https://remote.companyname.co.uk:987/default.aspx